# How to get the result containing KroneckerDelta in calculating orthogonality of the trigonometric system

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

With orthogonality of the trigonometric system, we have
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos n\theta \cos m\theta d\theta=\pi\delta_{nm}$$
But I can't get the result containing `KroneckerDelta`, my code is as follows

```
    Integrate[Cos[n θ] Cos[m θ], {θ, -π, π}, 
     Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0 && m ∈ Integers]
```

I get the result

> (2 m Cos[n π] Sin[m π] - 2 n Cos[m π] Sin[n π])/(m^2 - n^2)

Comment: Although you can use `Refine[output, Assumptions ->  n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 && m \[Element] Integers]` to simplify it to 0, Mathematica is not considering the case where `m==n` when doing the integration. Perhaps you can use `Assumption->m==n` to obtain a specific result.

Comment: It still doesn't obtain KroneckerDelta.

Comment: I didn't say you can, in fact I do not think it is possible with build in function.

Comment: @happyfish actually, it is considering that [case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754414/198315). The singularity is removable and the `Limit` exists.

Comment: This was discussed over on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7754414/198315) before the migration here. Essentially, your result is a `KroneckerDelta` in one of it's various forms. The answer I linked to will walk you through some ways of working with this.